# Auto Incrementing Variable Names

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to write a script where I fire a command (related to Chef) and get a list of clients. I have redirected that in a file and and now am reading from that file line by line. All this I could successfully do however the next part is proving to be pretty complicated. I will try to explain what I want to achieve. I want to assign these values fetched from line to a different variable. First take a look at the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/usrname/chef-repo
knife client list > /home/usrname/nodes.txt
NOL=`cat /home/usrname/nodes.txt | wc -l`       
for((i=1;i<=$NOL;i++))
do  
    VAR$i=`awk 'NR=='$i'{print $1}' /home/usrname/nodes.txt`
    echo `$VAR$i`
done
```

The O/P:

```
usrname@ubuntu:~/ShellScripts$ ./line.sh
./line.sh: line 9: VAR1=RhelVM: command not found
./line.sh: line 10: 1: command not found

./line.sh: line 9: VAR2=TrialNode: command not found
./line.sh: line 10: 2: command not found

./line.sh: line 9: VAR3=TrialNode2: command not found
./line.sh: line 10: 3: command not found

./line.sh: line 9: VAR4=WIN-OG02P1DGC30: command not found
./line.sh: line 10: 4: command not found

./line.sh: line 9: VAR5=vmnt-validator: command not found
./line.sh: line 10: 5: command not found
```

What I wanted this script to do is assign those node names to incrementing variable names respectively.

Eg. VAR1 will get assigned the value RhelVM
and `echo $VAR1` will return `RhelVM`,

VAR2 will get assigned TrialNode and and `echo $VAR2` will return `TrailNode` and so on.

As you guys can see, my approach is going horribly wrong. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use declare directive:

```
declare var$i=$(awk 'NR==$i{print $1; exit}' /home/usrname/nodes.txt)
```

- Better to use lowercase variable name to avoid collision with shell env variables.
- Better to call `exit` after print to make awk run fast.

Alternatively you can use `sed` to make it fast:

```
declare var$i=$(sed $i'q;d' /home/usrname/nodes.txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**process.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

i=1
while read -u5 n;
do
  varname="VAR$i"
  eval $varname=$n
  i=$((i+1))
done 5< nodes.txt

echo "VAR1 = $VAR1"
echo "VAR3 = $VAR3"
```

For **nodes.txt** with contents

```
RhelVM
TrialNode
TrialNode2
WIN-OG02P1DGC30
vmnt-validato
```

the result would be

```
[myhost]\> ./process.sh
VAR1 = RhelVM
VAR3 = TrialNode2
```

A better approach would be to use Bash arrays here (see this: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use an array.

```
cd /home/usrname/chef-repo
while read -r line; do
    VAR+=( "$line" )
done < <(knife client list)
```

If you have `bash` 4 or later, you can use `readarray` to replace the loop.

```
readarray -t VAR < <(knife client list)
```

Other notes:

- Use `NOL=$(wc -l < /home/usrname/nodes.txt)` to get the line count. But you won't need this variable. :)
- Use a `while` loop with `read` instead of a for loop that starts a new `awk` process just to read each line.
- Use process substitution `<( knife client list )` to avoid needing a temporary file.